# How to find record of conviction?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, criminal-record

My mother was convicted of something nearly 20 years ago in the UK, but since it was not worthy of prison forgot about the details soon after. I need to know about it in order to fully disclose information about everyone living in my house for an application I am making, but I don't know how to find out about details about this conviction. Is there an easy way to find out about someone's (or in this case, one's own) convictions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the offence was minor than it may be considered 'spent' under the [Rehabilitation of Offenders Act 1974](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1974/53/contents). A conviction resulting only in a fine is usually spent after five years. Spent convictions do not normally need to be disclosed, but you should check this with whoever is asking for the information.

Your mother can apply for a copy of her own criminal record by asking [Disclosure Scotland](https://www.disclosurescotland.co.uk) for a basic disclosure; this costs £25 and takes around two weeks if the application is made online. Due to a quirk in the Disclosure and Barring Service, this is the only way a person can apply for their own disclosure certificate.

Anyone in the UK can apply to Disclosure Scotland, even if they do not live in Scotland.